# Group rows in timeseries heat map by when they peak in columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am designing a heat map of the most highly regulated genes in a cell cycle time-series.

```
example <- read.csv("example.csv", header = T)

example.m <- melt(example)

(e <- ggplot(example.m, aes(variable, Gene_ID)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = 
value), colour = "white") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = 
"steelblue"))
```

And the results looks like this,

[example heat map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/innNw.png)

My values are log transformed, I am wondering if there is a way to order my rows so they group together by where they peak in the time-series (i.e all the genes that have their highest expression at 0 are grouped together, the genes with highest expression at 30 are grouped together, and so on.)
I tried to accomplish this like so

```
order <- arrange(example, X0, X30, X60, X90, X120, X150, X180, X210, X240)
```

and then went through the process of drawling the heat map with the ordered data frame, but it did not change.
Thank you for any help or advice you have to offer. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add this line to set the order of the Y axis `example.m$Gene_ID <- factor(example.m$Gene_ID, levels = order$Gene_ID, labels = order$Gene_ID)`

Here's the full code with some sample data:

```
example <- data.frame(Gene_ID = paste0("TTHERM_", 1:9),
                      X0 = round(runif(9, min =0, max = 4.4999),0), 
                      X30 = round(runif(9, min =0, max = 4.4999),0), 
                      X60 = round(runif(9, min =0, max = 4.4999),0), 
                      X90 = round(runif(9, min =0, max = 4.4999),0), 
                      X120 = round(runif(9, min =0, max = 4.4999),0),
                      X150 = round(runif(9, min =0, max = 4.4999),0),
                      X180 = round(runif(9, min =0, max = 4.4999),0),
                      X210 = round(runif(9, min =0, max = 4.4999),0),
                      X240 = round(runif(9, min =0, max = 4.4999),0))

library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
example.m <- melt(example)

# This is your original plot
(e <- ggplot(example.m, aes(variable, Gene_ID)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = 
                                                                  value), colour = "white") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = 
                                                                                                                    "steelblue"))
# Your order command gives us the right order
order <- arrange(example, X0, X30, X60, X90, X120, X150, X180, X210, X240)

# This changes the order of the Y axis based on the sort order
example.m$Gene_ID <- factor(example.m$Gene_ID, levels = order$Gene_ID, labels = order$Gene_ID)

# This is the new plot
(e <- ggplot(example.m, aes(variable, Gene_ID)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = 
                                                                  value), colour = "white") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = 
                                                                                                                    "steelblue"))
```

Original plot:

[image]

New plot:

[image]

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Close, I was hoping to order them by where they peek. If the expression is the highest at 0 it will be grouped together with others that have there highest expression at 0, and so on. I don't believe my arrange function accomplishes this, any suggestions?

Comment: You are grouping all the ones highest at zero together so I don't really understand what you want. You can't group the ones highest at zero together and also group the ones highest at 30 together at the same time.